# Ansible undefined variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-route53

i have role for Route53 (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/route53_module.html) and task is:

```
- name: "SET DNS record"
  route53:
    aws_access_key: "ACCESSKEY"
    aws_secret_key: "SECRET"
    command: "create"
    zone: "{{ dns_zone }}"
    hosted_zone_id: "{{ dns_zone_id }}"
    record: "{{ item.dns_record }}"
    type: "{{ item.dns_type }}"
    ttl: "{{ item.dns_ttl }}"
    value: "{{ item.dns_value }}"
    failover: "{{item.failover}}"
    health_check: "{{item.health_check}}"
    identifier: "{{item.identifier}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ dns_records }}"
```

Example of DNS records:

```
dns_records:
  - dns_record: "try1.example.com"
    dns_type: "A"
    dns_ttl: "3600"
    dns_value: "1.1.1.1"
    failover: "PRIMARY"
    health_check: "aeejas728asd"
    identifier: "identifier01"
  - dns_record: "try2.example.com"
    dns_type: "A"
    dns_ttl: "3600"
    dns_value: "2.2.2.2"
```

If i run paybook role FAILS because second value have undefined failover, health_check and identifier. How can i set expression for IF else?

My try:

```
identifier: "{{item.identifier if item.identifier is defined else '!'}}"
```

is not working. I need IF not defined THEN IGNORE VALUE.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_files_modules.html):

```
identifier: "{{item.identifier|default(omit)}}"
```